# Dragion yun shield ip address

Tags: arduino, arduino-yun

I just got an arduino yun shield by dragino.

I plugged into my computer usb with an Arduino uno following the instructions of the wiki and powering it from 5v > vin.

After a while the wifi network popped up, so I entered it. 
Went to http://192.168.240.1/ where I found the website / settings panel and added a password and connected to my own wifi network.

Now I have no idea how to get back to that website, what ip adress to use, or even how to reset those settings so it makes its own wifi network.

I can connect to the Arduino yun through the Arduino program, but I got  this error after just trying to do a blinking light. It does not show me the IP for it.

I have also tried connecting it to the wall outlet but it didn't create a network.

Is there anyway to completely reset the board?

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the shield was set to connect to your WiFi which in turn was set to get an IP address from your WiFi Router. If you want to find out what IP Address was assigned to the shield by the WiFi Router then you can go about it in two ways:

1. Log onto your WiFi Router and see if it contains a DHCP clients
   list. If the shield was assigned an IP from that router then it will be in that list as well.
2. Use software like SoftPerfect Network Scanner     (https://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/) to scan for         all hosts on your network. You can then see which IPs were assigned         to the hosts. One of them will most probably be the shield.

According to the shield's user manual you can reset to factory settings:

> 5.7 How to  reset the Yun Shield?  Yun Shield has a  toggle button which can be used for reset. When the system of Yun Shield is 
>   running, user can press the  toggle button to reset the device.   If
>   pressing the toggle button and release after  5 seconds , it will
>   reset the WiFi setting and  other settings will be kept.   If
>   pressing the toggle button and release after  30 second s , it will
>   reset  ALL the setting to  factory default.

Comment: Thank you! This seems like the answer. I will check it out in the morning.

Comment: I tried reseting it with 30 seconds, and 5 seconds but it still does not create its own network. Can find the DHCP clients list, and I dont know from what to what to scan on softperfect.

Comment: Ok so somehow after pressing the reset button 100 times for 30 seconds or 5 seconds it reset the wifi settings. So it started the dragino wifi network, I logged on and wrote down all the mac adresses ec, I then entered the network name and password it restarted and I connected to jenni, and the same thing happened. I tried soft perfect and it only found computer from 192.168.0.0 > 192.168.0.255. I also tried arp -a and it showed the same things.

Comment: Did you get this sorted, Manu?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options.

If you haven't changed the name of your Yun it's likely to have the default hostname: `arduino.local`, therefore, if the device has connected properly, you should be able to access it in the browser as http://arduino.local

This should work on OSX. On Windows you will need to use the Bonjour Service for this (which should come with iTunes for Windows). On Linux you can use `avahi`.

Another option is to ask your Yun what it's IP address is using an Arduino sketch and the USB cable. You can find some handy examples in **Arduino > File > Examples > Bridge**
I recommend checking out sketches like :

- WiFiStatus
- YunSerialTerminal
- ShellCommands

Either of these should allow you to get see useful info in Serial Monitor.
For example, if you send the `ifconfig` command via Serial Monitor.

Also, as Blurry Sterk already mentioned, you have the WiFi reset button which can reset the Wifi settings to default. By the way, with the default settings, the WiFi Access Point network name is

> Arduino Yun-XXXXXXXXXXXX", where the twelve 'X' are the MAC address of your Yún

(according to the [Arduino docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun)).

write it down (or at least the first 3 parts). You can see devices on your network along with the mac addresses using the `arp` command.

On Windows:

```
arp -a
```

On OSX:

```
arp -a -x -l
```

You can find the Yun's mac address in the list, and the IP from there.